# unable to understand the following j2me code

Tags: java, java-me

what this method do Specially the lines that are storing the string in url ..what is     8084/Filter/Shutdown,8084/Filter/ReStart,8084/Filter/NewServlet...plz help me i m working on a pc remote project

```
public test(Midlet midlet,String str,String ip)

{
if(str.equals("Shutdown"))
{
 Url="http://"+ip+":8084/Filter/Shutdown"   ;
}
if(str.equals("Restart"))
{
    Url="http://"+ip+":8084/Filter/Restart";
}
if(str.equals("File"))
{
    Url="http://"+ip+":8084/Filter/NewServlet";
}


display = Display.getDisplay(midlet);
}
```

Comment: btw: 1. As string can only have one value that euqals, you should use 'else if'. 2. Formatting is ugly ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your lines are constructing an `URL`.

`8084` is a Port Number. `/Filter/Shutdown` a path.

I'm quite certain that you have to set the URL to the midlet before displaying it.

Comment: but where this path is located ..is on a web server or something else.

Answer (score 0):

I guess if you run it and sniff traffic you learn alot about this application.
There is PC on network which listens on port 8084 and parsing GET Requests for commands. 
I am not sure what exactly confusing you.

Comment: Most likely everything here is confusing the OP. From the way the question is asked I would assume he has no idea what he's doing there. Most likely a beginner in Java or even any programming at all.